# Unable to replay commits of Linux kernel with git-format-patch and git-am

Tags: git

I want to fragment filesystem deliberately by replaying commits of Linux kernel. Firstly, I create patches with `git-format-patch`:

```
# in the existing Linux source code repo cloned from web
git format-patch --root origin
```

Then, merge the patches with `git-am`

```
# in the new repo init with `git init`, and apply the patches one by one
git am path/to/the/patch
```

It works well at first but crashed at `0226-PATCH-consolidate-timeout-defintions-in-scsi.h.patch` soon.

```
error: patch failed: drivers/block/scsi_ioctl.c:328
error: drivers/block/scsi_ioctl.c: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: drivers/scsi/scsi_ioctl.c:27
error: drivers/scsi/scsi_ioctl.c: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: include/scsi/scsi.h:360
error: include/scsi/scsi.h: patch does not apply
```

So, why `git-format-output` and `git-am` fail the job and how to fix it?

Comment: @eftshift0 the repo is inited with `git init` and apply patches from the first one named `0001-Linux-2.6.12-rc2.patch`

Comment: Oh.... so you asked to run from --root... so you are basically replicating the linux kernel history on a different tree. Ok... this is interesting. I would _assume_ that `format-patch` won't produce merge revisions that introduce no real changes.... and then `am` won't be able to accurately reproduce the patches because I would _assume_ that it would be reapplied on a single line, not with the original branches... therefore patches  might fail to apply.... but I would like to see a real answer... that's just _a guess_ on my part.

Comment: What happens if you try with `-3`? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git format-patch` necessarily turns all history linear.

That is, suppose you have a repository with exactly these 14 commits:

```
             I--J
            /    \
A--B--...--H      M--N   <-- master
            \    /
             K--L
```

Note that the 13th commit is a *merge*, combining commits `J` (tenth) and `L` (twelfth).

The `git format-patch` program will *omit* commit `M` entirely, and produce a patch series of 13 commits, in which commits `K-L` and `I-J` are in the right order with respect to each other, but are in some random pairing order.

Applying this series of patches to an empty repository will produce:

```
A'-B'-...--H'-I'-J'-K'-L'-N'  <-- master
```

or:

```
A'-B'-...--H'-K'-L'-I'-J'-N'  <-- master
```

if all goes well.  However, whichever of commits `I-J` or `K-L` come *second* may have merge conflicts with the prior pair, and commit `N` may also have merge conflicts, all depending on what happened in original commit `M`, which is no longer in the new history.

Note that `git rebase` omits merges by default, and linearizes the history in the same way.  This is in part because `git rebase` was originally implemented as `git format-patch | git am`.